# Gem cannot be found after running bundle install in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundler

I am trying to install a Rails 4 app and run it on my Mac.
One Gem is causing problems. In my Gemfile it's the line:

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-datatables'
end
```

Running `bundle` seems to install the Gem

```
Fetching rails-assets-datatables 1.10.16
Installing rails-assets-datatables 1.10.16
```

But when I try to start my server `rails s` I get

```
Could not find rails-assets-datatables-1.10.16 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

My Gem Lockfile shows:

```
rails-assets-datatables (1.10.16)
```

So it seems that the Gem has been installed but either to a wrong destination or gets deleted again right after the installation.

The app uses many other Gems without problem. When I run `bundle` again it installs the datatables Gem again as if it was not installed yet.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Try executing `gem list`

Comment: Try deleting the Gemfile.lock and running bundle again